# Rails Localization control panel module with one language and other with two language

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have web site which control panel have only one language and the website with two language
I have control panel in namespace admin.I use bellow code to in application controller to set up local lang based on user browser headers

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

        #to set local
         before_filter :set_locale

       private
           def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
             request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
            end

          def set_locale
            I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || I18n.default_locale
            Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale]= I18n.locale
          end



         end
```

this code sets all site language , any way to set control panel with only one language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas how to solve it (not sure which one is the best):

- Use different locale files for the control panel and the rest, and link the other language control panel files to the default locale files (English normally).
- Override in your control panel controller the method `set_locale` and return all the time `en` here (or whatever default locale you want to have).

See the [Rails Internationalization Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the cleanest way, I know but this is how I got round it:

```
def set_locale
    if Rails.env.test? then
        I18n.locale = 'en'
        cookies[:location] = 'en'
    else
        logger.debug "* Accept-Language: #{request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']}"
        I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
        logger.debug "* Locale set to '#{I18n.locale}'"
    end
end
```

You could always monkey patch this in your spec helper like so:

```
ApplicationController.class_eval do
    def set_locale
        I18n.locale = 'en'
    end
end
```

This way you'd keep your ApplicationController clean